# Why is R converting dates to integer?

Tags: r

I have two objects:

```
Ux <- as.Date(c("2019-02-02", "2019-03-03", "2019-04-04","2019-05-05"))

df <- data.frame(date= c("2019-04-04", "2019-04-08","2019-03-22","2019-04- 
  02","2019-04-11"),Score=c(1,2,4,5,6))
```

I need the next date from Ux based on the date in df. So i loop through df, and check the date. The next date from Ux is inserted in df

```
for (i in 1:NROW(df)){
       df$dt[i] <- subset(Ux, Ux >=df$date[i])[1]
      }
```

But no.. the date is now a number... i have tried some variations around this.. any suggestion to how to fix this?

```
df.expected <- data.frame(date= c("2019-04-04", "2019-04-08","2019-03- 
22","2019-04-02","2019-04-11"),
                         Score=c(1,2,4,5,6),
                     dt = c("2019-04-04", "2019-05-05", "2019-04-04", "2019-04-04","2019-05-05"))
```

Comment: You are using `subset` on a `vector` i.e. Ux.  What is the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
# setup environment
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
# define data
Ux <- ymd(c("2019-02-02", "2019-03-03", "2019-04-04","2019-05-05"))
df <- data.frame(date = ymd(c("2019-04-04", "2019-04-08", "2019-03-22",
                                  "2019-04-02", "2019-04-11")),
                 Score = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6))
# create a new variable using mutate()
df = mutate(df, dt = Reduce(c, lapply(df$date, function(x, y)  y[y >= x][1], Ux)))
df
```

Here is the output:

```
        date Score         dt
1 2019-04-04     1 2019-04-04
2 2019-04-08     2 2019-05-05
3 2019-03-22     4 2019-04-04
4 2019-04-02     5 2019-04-04
5 2019-04-11     6 2019-05-05
```

It's important to note that you cannot use `subset()` on a vector, you should subset it using `[]` combined with a logical vector inside.

I chose for `lapply()` instead of `sapply()`, because `sapply()` do not return dates, therefore, I had to use `Reduce()` to convert the output (a list) into a vector.